# Throw exception from within a future

Tags: scala

I need to throw an exception in my program, but the exception happens within a future, so it is thrown in a different thread. How to make this example work?

```
object TestFutures extends App {

  val f0 = Future { 0 }
  val f1 = Future { 1 }
  val fx = Seq(f0,f1)

  fx.map { 
    seq => seq.map {  i =>
        println("i="+i)
        if (i == 1)
              throw new Exception("This is an exception")

    }
  }


  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

This is the program output, but I need it to throw the exception:

```
i=0
i=1
```

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking-outside-the-future

Comment: The exception *is* being thrown *in* your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result is still a Future

```
 val stillFutures: Seq[Future[Unit]] = fx.map {
    seq => seq.map {  i =>
      println("i="+i)
      if (i == 1)
        throw new Exception("This is an exception")

    }
  }
```

You can check each future on Success/Failure

```
stillFutures.foreach{
_.onComplete{
  case Success(_) => // do nothing
  case Failure(ex) => throw ex
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > How to make this example work?

You can use `for` to make it work as

```
val f0 = Future { 0 }
val f1 = Future { 1 }
val fx = Seq(f0,f1)

for(seq <- fx){
  for(i <- seq) {
    println("i="+i)
    if (i == 1) {
      throw new Exception("This is an exception")
    }
  }
}
Thread.sleep(5000)
```